# Create a branch after some commits

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Yesterday a developer made a big commit in the master that break some code and do not create a branch previously to do this.

The commit list is:

```
+ da1cd10  --> HEAD
+ 48f70a1
+ 3b94ae5
+ a808c65
+ 92ee96f  --> Commit starting changes
+ 194dc5c
+ 2e2c5e0
|
master
```

The commit "92ee96f" move files, added several folders that impact the other developers. All commits listed above are in the bitbucket.

Now, I need to separate the commit "92ee96f" in a specific branch and continue the master with the other commits like below:

```
        master   
        |
        | new branch
        | |
da1cd10 + |  
48f70a1 + | 
3b94ae5 + | 
a808c65 + | 
        | + 92ee96f  --> Commit starting changes
        |/
        + 194dc5c
        + 2e2c5e0
        |
       master
```

Is that possible? and how I have to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will break your solution in two steps:

**Step1:** Creating a branch for **92ee96f** commit.

So, use the below command for creating a new branch:

> git checkout -b new-branch **194dc5c**

Now your new branch is having HEAD at 194dc5c commit. Cherry-pick your required commit to this new-branch.

> git cherry-pick **92ee96f**

Now you have a new branch with 92ee96f commit as required.

**Step2:** Removing **92ee96f**  commit from your tree of master branch.

If you have already pushed the commit, then use **"git revert 92ee96f"** command.

Otherwise, use the below command to remove this commit.

> git rebase -i HEAD

This will start the rebase in interactive mode -i at the point just before the commit you want to whack. The editor will start up listing all of the commits since then. Delete the line containing the commit you want to obliterate and save the file. Rebase will do the rest of the work, deleting only that commit, and replaying all of the others back into the log.
Then if you want to push your changes,

> git push --force origin master

I hope my answer will fulfill the intention of your question.

Comment: Great! That's work! Just remember that the step2 is necessary the command 'git checkout master'.

Comment: Oh missed that, anyway i am happy that my answer was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : After reading the question again, I'm not sure my answer is what you want. I assumed you wish to move all the commits starting in `92ee96f` to the new-branch.

My answer is based on an example from this [great article](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

When you have the master branch checked out, do

```
git branch new-branch
```

"master" and "new-branch" would both point to the last commit - `da1cd10`

```
  git checkout master
```

# Be careful with this next command: make sure "git status" is
  # clean, you're definitely on "master" and the
  # "new-branch" branch has all the commits made after commit 194dc5c.

```
  git reset --hard <SHA1sum of commit 194dc5c>
```

Now master would point to 194dc5c and new-branch to da1cd10.

Then when you add new commits to master (e.g. a808c65), you get what you want

```
  2e2c5e0--194dc5c---- ... --- ... ---  ... ("master")
               \
                92ee96f  --- ... --- da1cd10   ("new-branch")
```

Comment: Your answer is valid, but the commit 'da1cd10' is not belonged to the new branch.